# javax.time in Kotlin

Tags: java-8, kotlin, jodatime, jsr310

I tried following code to use javax.time in Kotlin:

```
import javax.time.calendar.LocalDate

fun main(args: Array<String>){
  println("Today is ${LocalDate.now()}");
}
```

And got compilation error:

```
C:\kotlin-hello-world>kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
hello.kt:1:14: error: unresolved reference: time
import javax.time.calendar.LocalDate
             ^
```

And google search shows in Kotlin javax.time can not be used and people recommend to use [ThreeTenBP](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp) with [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) if android. My use case is use javax.time classes in server side with Kotlin.

But when I tried to use TreeTenBP, I have to import `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate` instead of `javax.time.calendar.LocalDate` as TreeTen* is not implementation of JSR-310 but back port.

Is there any way to use javax.time in Kotlin other than those backport libraries? If so, how to configure such environment or how to write such code?

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: java -version --> java version "1.8.0_92"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`javax.time` is a dead package.

Use `java.time` in Java SE 8.
Or `org.threeten.bp` for the backport.

Comment: I was about to suggest JodaTime as an alternative for java 6 or 7, but if the author of that library himself is suggesting you use a backport of `java.time`...

Comment: @Groostav He is also the specification lead for JSR 310